# Textures bake transparency as white

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, transparency, texture-baking

I'm trying to bake tile maps into a single texture for someone and I'm having difficulties baking transparency.
For example one texture is literally transparency with baked shadows but this bakes as a white texture with gray shading.
All images are .tga format and are between 128^2 and 512^2 resolution.

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: I figured it all out now, sorry about that. Turns out I needed to adjust the alpha under ztransparency.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, you need to edit the alpha and specular values under Z Transparency and turn on the Alpha influence.

Basically, remove the Alpha and Specular values entirely(Set to 0 or -1, can't remember which) under the Z Transparency in the Material Editor. Then, under the Influence tab in the texture editor, add the Alpha channel and then shift it to 0.

Comment: Could you add a little more information for others who might come across this answer such as what the alpha and specular values had to be changed to?

Comment: This solved my problem but the difference is that in "material", I could leave Specular to 1 and in "texture", I had to leave the alpha channel to 1. I also had to enable transparency in "object" properties: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/11053/why-is-the-alpha-channel-not-working/11054#comment49221_11054

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, my baked texture didn't have transparency, instead the low-poly object was visible too, in solid white. What FSLuaGuy wrote worked for me! Here's the details:

- In the Material settings of the low-poly object set Alpha and Specular to 0 [image: Transparency settings of the low-poly object]
- In the Texture settings add the Alpha channel and set it to 0 (not -1!) [image]

Comment: at newer versions of blender you need to set the texture alpha to 1 instead of 0

Comment: @TRBlount I have a similar problem. (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182836/bake-transparent-mesh-plane-decal-always-shows-transparent-pixels-as-black)  I would be really glad if you may take a look. Thanks.