# Cycles bakes a transparent areas to black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, texture-baking

With Cycles, rendering transparent texture is OK, but baking turns alpha to black color. In contrast, Blender Internal bakes alpha OK. What should I do with nodes in Cycles? Help plz.

P.S. Maybe the problem is  https://developer.blender.org/rBf3505ab771184877413cfa11336da2ccc1da36ee

[image: Cycles baking alpha as black]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textures bake transparency as white](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15185/textures-bake-transparency-as-white)

Comment: Blender Render works fine, it's only Cycles issue!