# Baking transparent decal always results in black oblique pixels

Tags: texture-baking

I have 3 mesh planes.

- A's texture =transparent decal
- B's texture =oblique texture
- C's texture =result of baking

These 3 planes are places on top of each other.
[image]
When I bake, transparent pixels of `A` will always appear as **black** in `C` which is wrong!
[image]
How to bake it correctly?  The result should be similar to the `A+B` image.

[image]

In real case,  the objects are more complex than this, and I use shrinkwarp for `A`(decal) on `B`.

**Related** : [Cycles bakes a transparent areas to black](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66743/cycles-bakes-a-transparent-areas-to-black) , [Textures bake transparency as white](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15185/textures-bake-transparency-as-white)

I prefer to not use any paid add-on.
I don't mind coding Python myself.

Comment: When creating an image for your bake, did you check "use alpha" and "32-bit float"?

Comment: @Christopher Bennett  I didn't check, do you mean A or B or C or all?

Comment: Actually, now that I look at the file, I think you should also apply alpha-clip to the shadow mode in addition to the blend mode on the decal.

Comment: @Christopher ...  All textures (ABC) are 256*256, RGBA byte, Color space= sRGB, Alpha=Straight.

Comment: And I meant C, but I can see that the alpha works on the edges, so I don't think that's the problem. I think what's happening is that you have an opaque shadow on the decal even though you clipped the alpha on the image. When you bake it, it's casting a black (shadow) box. I think if you change the shadow mode to alpha clip as well and bake again, it should work.

Comment: @Christopher  I set `Material Properties>Viewport display>Setting>` of all ABC to both `Shadow Mode` and `Blend Mode` = `Alpha Clip`.    Problem still exists.  I don't think it is related because the setting is called `viewport display`, not bake/render.

Comment: @Christopher The alpha that works on the edges may be the effect of bleeding. The `C` mesh is bigger than `B`.

Comment: Hmm. Strange. I really thought that would do it. Hang on, I'm trying some things....

Comment: Hey, so yeah, the things I tried aren't working either. I't's getting late where I am, and I'm tired. I will take a look in the morning when I am more rested and hopefully a solution will be more clear. Best of luck in the meantime, hopefully my help won't be needed anymore by then.

Comment: @Christopher  Thank for your attempt.  Yeah, it is hard. I messed with it for 4 hours already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is not directly possible.

Though, a workaround is to use an intermediate surface which is glass, combined with emission (as this setting darkens the surfaces).

Then, bake (transmission) from it to the target plane.

[image]

A and B are inverted from initial setting

[image]

As (poor) explanation, my hypothesis about why it works is [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/introduction.html#transparency-rays):

> The transparent BSDF shader is given special treatment. When a ray
> passes through it, light passes straight on, as if there was no
> geometry there. **The ray type does not change when passing through a
> transparent BSDF**.

And:

> Note that, while semantically the ray passes through as if no geometry
> was hit, rendering performance is affected as each transparency step
> requires executing the shader and tracing a ray.

So (maybe), from the raycast point of view (actual or calculated baking cage) the A surface keeps the ray black whilst going through it, except for the rays it diffuses itself.

Is it a bug or unmanaged situation, I don't know.

As opposite, the glass surface receives and keeps actual rays and can transmit them.

Additionnally, we could except that a setting where A is alpha driven mix between glass and diffuse should work (in the initial A on B on C case) but it does not.

Note: edited also because I was wrong thinking changing *"film"* parameters was needed.

Comment: That's a brilliant workaround!  The image doesn't seem to get darker unless you disable caustics (and I distrust the mix with emission), but I haven't gone in with a magnifying glass.  IOR probably ought to be 1.0, although in this case it doesn't matter (perpendicular rays.)  Use of a refraction BSDF instead of glass ought to eliminate risk of specular for glancing rays as well.