# XPS and Blender-Transparency problem

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

I'm importing an .OBJ file. This is how it looks like when imported to Blender.

[image]

I don't want the transparent parts of the texture to be colored white.

I believe I need to adjust the Alpha channels to get rid of the white parts?

I'm in the Blender Render, Viewport Shading-Texture.

Comment: Hi Alice, Welcome to Blender.se. I have removed some text from your question, it's very clear without it. You have to **enable alpha**. Please search for texturing with alpha on Google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the alpha channel not working?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/11053/why-is-the-alpha-channel-not-working)

Comment: Thank you! I will search and hopefully, I can understand to fix this issue.

Comment: @Leander Consider writing up an answer so we can mark this question answered

Comment: @Kirbinator But it's a dupe, isn't it?

Comment: @Leander: That judgement hasn't been officially made yet, might as well go for broke